# Why am I getting an empty body tag content when trying to use web scraping using the requests library?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have been trying to use web scraping on a website using the requests and Beautifulsoup python libraries.
The problem is that I'm getting the html data of the web page but the body tag content is empty while on the inspect panel on the website it isn't.
Does anyone can explain why is it happening and what can I do to get the content of the body?

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://webaccess-il.rexail.com/?s_jwe=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..gKfb7AnqhUiIMIn0PGb35g.SUsLS70gBec9GBgraaV5BK8hKyqm-VvMSNjP3nIumtcrj9h19zOkYjaBHrW4SDL10DjeIcwQcz9ul1p8umMHKxPPC-QZpCyJbk7JQkUSqFM._d_sGsiSyPF_Xqs2hmLN5A#/store-products-shopping-non-customers').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Here is the inspect panel of the website:

[image]

And here is the output of my code:

[image]

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons, your code could not work for. The fist one is, the website does require additional `header` or `cookie` information, that you could try to find using the Inspect Browser Tool and add via

```
requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
```

where `headers` and `cookies` are dictionaries.

Another reason, which I believe it is, is that the content is dynamically loaded via `Javascript` after the side is build, and what you do get is the initially loaded website.

To also provide you a solution, I attache an example using Selenium, which simulates a whole browser, which does serve the full website, however selenium has a bit of a setup overhead, that you can easily google.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://webaccess-il.rexail.com/?s_jwe=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..gKfb7AnqhUiIMIn0PGb35g.SUsLS70gBec9GBgraaV5BK8hKyqm-VvMSNjP3nIumtcrj9h19zOkYjaBHrW4SDL10DjeIcwQcz9ul1p8umMHKxPPC-QZpCyJbk7JQkUSqFM._d_sGsiSyPF_Xqs2hmLN5A#/store-products-shopping-non-customers'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
sleep(10)
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
```

If you want the browser simulation to be none visible you can add

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

which will make it run in the backgroud.

Alternatively to Firefox, you can use pretty much any browser using the appropriate driver.

A Linux based setup example can be found here [Link](https://linuxhint.com/selenium-web-automation-python/)

Answer (score 1):

Even though I find the use of Selenium easier for beginners, that site bothered me, so I figured out a pure `requests` way, that I also want to share.

Process:
When you look at the network traffic after loading the website, you find a lot of outgoing get requests. Assuming, you are interested in the products, that are loaded, I found a call right above the product images being loaded from Amazon S3 going to

```
https://client-il.rexail.com/client/public/public-catalog?s_jwe=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..gKfb7AnqhUiIMIn0PGb35g.SUsLS70gBec9GBgraaV5BK8hKyqm-VvMSNjP3nIumtcrj9h19zOkYjaBHrW4SDL10DjeIcwQcz9ul1p8umMHKxPPC-QZpCyJbk7JQkUSqFM._d_sGsiSyPF_Xqs2hmLN5A
```

importantly

```
https://client-il.rexail.com/client/public/public-catalog?s_jwe=[...]
```

Upon clicking the URL I found it to be indeed a JSON of the products. However the `s_jwe` token is dynamic and without it, the JSON doesn't load.

Now investigating the initially loading url and searching for `s_jwe` you will find

```
<script>
            window.customerStore = {store: angular.fromJson({"id":26,"name":"\u05de\u05e9\u05e7 \u05d4\u05e8 \u05e4\u05e8\u05d7\u05d9\u05dd","imagePath":"images\/stores\/26\/88aa6827bcf05f9484b0dafaedf22b0a.png","secondaryImagePath":"images\/stores\/4d5d1f54038b217244956071ca62312d.png","thirdImagePath":"images\/stores\/26\/2f9294180e7d656ba7280540379869ee.png","fourthImagePath":"images\/stores\/26\/bd2861565b18613497a6ce66903bf9eb.png","externalWebTrackingAccounts":"[{\"accountType\":\"googleAnalytics\",\"identifier\":\"UA-130110792-1\",\"primaryDomain\":\"ecomeshek.co.il\"},{\"accountType\":\"facebookPixel\",\"identifier\":\"3958210627568899\"}]","worksWithStoreCoupons":false,"performSellingUnitsEstimationLearning":false}), s_jwe: "eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..gKfb7AnqhUiIMIn0PGb35g.SUsLS70gBec9GBgraaV5BK8hKyqm-VvMSNjP3nIumtcrj9h19zOkYjaBHrW4SDL10DjeIcwQcz9ul1p8umMHKxPPC-QZpCyJbk7JQkUSqFM._d_sGsiSyPF_Xqs2hmLN5A"};
            const externalWebTrackingAccounts = angular.fromJson(customerStore.store.externalWebTrackingAccounts);
        </script>
```

containing

```
s_jwe: "eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..gKfb7AnqhUiIMIn0PGb35g.SUsLS70gBec9GBgraaV5BK8hKyqm-VvMSNjP3nIumtcrj9h19zOkYjaBHrW4SDL10DjeIcwQcz9ul1p8umMHKxPPC-QZpCyJbk7JQkUSqFM._d_sGsiSyPF_Xqs2hmLN5A"
```

So to summerize, even though, the initial page does not contain the products, it does contain the token and the product url.

Now you can extract the two and call the product catalog directly as such:

**FINAL CODE:**

```
import requests
import re
import json

s = requests.Session()

initial_url = 'https://webaccess-il.rexail.com/?s_jwe=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..gKfb7AnqhUiIMIn0PGb35g.SUsLS70gBec9GBgraaV5BK8hKyqm-VvMSNjP3nIumtcrj9h19zOkYjaBHrW4SDL10DjeIcwQcz9ul1p8umMHKxPPC-QZpCyJbk7JQkUSqFM._d_sGsiSyPF_Xqs2hmLN5A#/store-products-shopping-non-customers'
initial_site = s.get(url= initial_url).content.decode('utf-8')

jwe = re.findall(r's_jwe:.*"(.*)"', initial_site)

product_url = "https://client-il.rexail.com/client/public/public-catalog?s_jwe="+ jwe[0]
products_site = s.get(url= product_url).content.decode('utf-8')
products = json.loads(products_site)["data"]
print(products[0])
```

There is a little bit of finetuning required with the decoding, but I am sure you can manage that. ;)

This of course is the leaner way of scraping that website, but as I hopefully showed, scraping is always a bit of playing Sherlock Holmes.

Any questions, glad to help.

Comment: Thank you for the great answers! I will try it :)